# A point in Ion Suciu's paper on semigroups of isometric operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

My question is concerned  a point in [this 1968 paper by Ion Suciu](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm30/sm30111.pdf) which is given in Theorem 2. In the last paragraph of page 104, it is claimed that $N$ (given in the formula 2.5) is a wandering subspace. I do not get this point.

(Reference: I. Suciu, On the semi-groups of isometries. Studia Math. 30 1968 101-110.)

Comment: That's not a well-defined author's name!

Comment: @ Alex Suciu I got from the paper. What do you mean?

Comment: There is not a unique mathematician by that name, that's all.